# UPDATE MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php, update, sql

Всем доброго времени суток. Казалось бы, банальная проблема, однако я с ней вожусь уже часа два, может, вы мне поможете. Я не исключаю ошибку в коде, кодировке или ещё где-либо, но то, что  не работает именно эта строка, остаётся фактом.

Попробовал через такой синтаксис запроса добавления — не получается:

```
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE places_users SET surname='$new_surname' WHERE email='$email'");
```

Попробовал через такой, аналогично — не работает:

```
$query = "UPDATE `places_users` SET `name`='$new_name'  WHERE `id`='$id'"; mysql_query($query);
```

Кто знает, как с такой проблемой быть? Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: А вы как с этой проблемой возитесь?

Comment: вардампните запрос и попробуйте его выполнить через pma, если ошибка в нем, pma скажет об этом. Если ошибка не в запросе, то надо копать в сторону подключения к бд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Проблема оказалась в условии. Просто не совсем верно был построен код.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result_query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```